# Sobre o "tempo de espera" nas requisições quando o site é carregado(desempenho)

Tags: desempenho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estava vendo o tempo de Load do site, e percebi que a barrinha azul(que diz sobre espera), está bem grandinha.

Gostaria de saber porquê isso acontece, se isso pode ser porquê o servidor que estou pegando o dado esteja lento, ou se isso é normal, ou se ainda existe algum "limite" de quantos dados simultâneos por servidor para pegar, ou se isso tem a ver com a questão dos cookies que são carregados juntos com a requisição(quando feitas para o meu próprio servidor).

Não sei se essa questão faz jus fazer no fórum da Stack.. Me desculpe se estou errada..

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas o assunto é gigante e daria um artigo acadêmico. Então vou te indicar alguns links já que vc está interessada. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/ aqui tem outro interessante em português. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/mobile . Já sobre a Barra Azul grande é porque o arquivo tem 0kb, muito provavelmente é uma referencia no sua página que o browser procurou e não achou no servidor. Pesquise tb sobre o HTTP2 ele vai resolver vários problemas de requisição por trabalhar de forma assíncrona

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo comentário e pelas indicações de leitura. ;)